# Find the customer name of any customers who have an interest in ALL artists

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for customer name of any customers who have an interest in all artists. I am not sure how to get it using sql. Needed help here.

I have these tables with columns.

```
Artist (ARTISTID,LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME)

Customer (CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME)

CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT (ARTISTID, CUSTOMERID)
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: it is in sql. using oracle sql developer to do the query

Comment: any advise aleksej?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the customer ids by doing:

```
select customerid
from customer_artist_int cai
group by customerid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from artist);
```

You can then use a `join` or `in` to get the rest of the customer information.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to approach such problems is to invert them - find all the customers for which there exists no artist they aren't interested in. It may sound a bit convoluted in English, but when you convert it to SQL, it becomes quite elegant:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   artist a
                   JOIN   customer_artist_int cai ON a.artistid = cai.artistid
                   WHERE  cai.customerid = c.customerid)
```

Comment: Is your query somehow "inverted"? It seems that you get all the customers that are interested in no artists; am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, Thanks for query code. It works but not sure whether it is corrrect because my qns is looking for name of any customers having interest in all artists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understad well, this may be a way

**Setup:**

```
create table Artist (ARTISTID,LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME) as
select '1', 'lastname_artist_1', 'first_name_artist_1' from dual union all
select '2', 'lastname_artist_2', 'first_name_artist_2' from dual union all
select '3', 'lastname_artist_3', 'first_name_artist_3' from dual 

create table Customer (CUSTOMERID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME) as
select '1', 'lastname_customer_1', 'first_name_customer_1' from dual union all
select '2', 'lastname_customer_2', 'first_name_customer_2' from dual union all
select '3', 'lastname_customer_3', 'first_name_customer_3' from dual

create table CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT (ARTISTID, CUSTOMERID) as
select 1, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 1 from dual union all
select 3, 1 from dual union all
select 2, 2 from dual
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
         LASTNAME,
         FIRSTNAME,
         COUNT(DISTINCT artistid)
    FROM customer c INNER JOIN customer_artist_int USING (customerid)
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID,
         LASTNAME,
         FIRSTNAME
  HAVING COUNT(artistid) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Artist)
```

Here you count the number of artstis that every customer is interested in and check if it is equal to the number of all the artists.

Comment: nice.. think this is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think mine is the most elegant of all answers, but here is my attempt..

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME, c.CUSTOMERID
FROM DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER c, DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai
WHERE c.CUSTOMERID = cai.CUSTOMERID 
AND c.CUSTOMERID IN 
(SELECT cai.CUSTOMERID
  FROM DTOOHEY.CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT cai
  GROUP BY cai.CUSTOMERID
  HAVING COUNT (*) = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DTOOHEY.ARTIST)
)
GROUP BY c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME, c.CUSTOMERID;
```

based on my limited knowledge, the flow of command is:

1) I am trying to get the customer ID, first name and last name of customer 

2) I am getting it from the 2 tables (cai and c)

3) trying to join the 2 tables to give me a single data set

4) where the c.customerid is to be gathered in...

this is where the magic begins!!!

5) select the customerID (the single CustomerID)

6) from this table cai

7) group the result based on customerID, this is what gives the single CustomerID Value that you need...

8) having COUNT (*) - having the count of customerID value, to that of equal of the number of count of artists in the dtoohey.artist table.


the main logic is that the number of artist in the artist table (which is 11), exist in the CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT in the same quantity. As such, we can tally the result of count from the ARTIST Table into the CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT table.